# Is there ever a reason to use git clean without -f?

Tags: git

As I understand it, the purpose of `git clean` is to delete untracked files. But it won't (by default) run without the `-f` flag. I can understand the `-f` flag for commands that do something *besides* delete stuff, because I might run them to do one thing, without realizing that it will also delete files as a side-effect. But if I run `git clean`, I *know* I'll be deleting files.

Is this just a safety mechanism, like an "Are you sure" popup? Or is there actually something else `git clean` can do without the `-f` flag?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName I don't really see how that's related...

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That answer explains what `-f` does, but not why it exists.

Comment: Maybe you accept one of the answers? Or is anything left unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it won't (by default) run without the -f flag.

Actually, `git clean` will refuse to perform anything unless you specify `-f`, `-i` or `-n`. You are required to specify at least one of them.

`-n`is for "dry run" (showing what would be done without actually deleting files). The two others one act just like the `rm` command. "force" (silently deleting everything that matches) or "interactive" (explicitly ask the user for each matching file).

> Is this just a safety mechanism, like an "Are you sure" popup?

To my eyes, that's indeed an efficient way to introduce the thing.

**git clean** is actually very dangerous, as it looks like a common command but actually will delete everything that is not already stored, which would make of it one of the rare commands that may actually loose data with no hope of recovery. Knowing that most of beginners already rush into "git checkout -f" and "git reset --hard", we easily understand that such a security step is not useless.

In particular, "`git clean -f`" would delete every **new** file that has not been added **yet** ! This could be for example a brand new module you've been writing all day for the project you're working on.

Also, when git is used to work on a software development project (that is, the most frequent use case) one could assume that "`git clean`" works the same way that "`make clean`", which would be a big mistake. The latter one is made to clean up its own crap and knows exactly what to look for. Git would do the opposite.

The normal way of working for a SCM is to never touch what has not explicitly been tracked once. `git clean` is essentially made to either restore the initial state of an existing repository to avoid having to drop it and re-clone it again, or to actually clean up everything that's useless once we've done with a big task, before starting sharing the thing.

If I was a system administrator and if this was possible, I would configure `git clean`'s default behavour as `-i`, instead of simply prompting user with available options, just like `rm` is on most distributions. This shows a message telling exactly what is currently being done and give a chance to people that don't know what they do to stop before it's too late. Simply being prompted for '-f', '-i' or '-n' is a risk for the user to opt for '-f' by default.

Comment: "one of the rare commands that would lose data without recovery" - I feel like that's not that rare. `rm`?

Comment: @Kolob Canyon : I meant "one of the rare **git** commands". There's actually many ways of losing data with git, and `git rm` is _not_ one of them (provided you already have committed your files once).

`git checkout`, for instance, won't clobber your files neither if you try to change your branch having uncommited files in your repository, unless you explicitly use `-f`, what most of beginners actually do when they're stuck, as explained above. `make clean`, however, can be called in good faith and definitely requires these safety mechanisms.

Comment: `make clean` is not designed to do anything, it does what is written in the Makefile. Also, I don't understand how you are trying to explain why a safety mechanism is needed for `git clean` by arguing how `make clean` can delete stuff.

Comment: I just noticed I meant "git clean" at the beginning of my fourth paragraph. :-\ Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the commit where the `-f` option was included:

https://github.com/git/git/commit/2122591b3b5c6d93d3052a3151afcfa3146ede84#diff-3099dbcff3411d798a74588a2638748e

It says:

> Add clean.requireForce option, and add -f option to git-clean to over…
>
> …ride it
>
> Add a new configuration option clean.requireForce.  If set, git-clean will
>   refuse to run, unless forced with the new -f option, or not acting due to -n.

Later fixed: https://github.com/git/git/commit/89c38500192e00988966246420902dc946e4f4ef#diff-3099dbcff3411d798a74588a2638748e

> git-clean: fix the description of the default behavior
>
> Currently, when called without -n and -f, git clean issues
>
> fatal: clean.requireForce not set and -n or -f not given; refusing to
>   clean
>
> which leaves the user wondering why force is required when
>   requireForce is not set. Looking up in git-clean(1) does not help
>   because its description is wrong.
>
> Change it so that git clean issues
>
> fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and -n or -f not given;
>   refusing to clean
>
> in this situation (and "...set to true..." when it is set) which makes
>   it clearer that an unset config means true here, and adjust the
>   documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are untracked files and directories and you run `git clean`. It will print `fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -i, -n, nor -f given; refusing to clean`.

So without `-f`, you could do something like

`git -c clean.requireForce=false clean -d`, which is the same with `git clean -df`;

`git clean -dn`, which will do a dry-run and just tells what would be removed without actually removing anything;

`git clean -id`, which allows you to interactively remove untracked files and directories;

`git clean -nX`, which tells which ignored files would be removed.

I agree it's a safety mechanism. But as you see, it's not always necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> If I was a system administrator and if this was possible, I would configure git clean's default behavour as `-i`

That will be safer with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020): The interactive input from various codepaths are consolidated and any prompt possibly issued earlier are `fflush()`ed before we read.

See [commit 1f09aed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f09aed8346f11c9fd236940b6e500388c394af2) (10 Apr 2020) by [마누엘 (`nalla`)](https://github.com/nalla).
See [commit 08d383f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08d383f23e80e418c844952fcc4e2e635962c292) (10 Apr 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 33feaca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33feaca6bfec2b80bcb915cfb477dcb3b14c7ef0), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`interactive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f09aed8346f11c9fd236940b6e500388c394af2): explicitly `fflush` stdout before expecting input
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: 마누엘</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> At least one interactive command writes a prompt to `stdout` and then reads user input on `stdin`: `git clean --interactive`.
> **If the prompt is left in the buffer, the user will not realize the program is waiting for their input.**
>
> So let's just flush `stdout` before reading the user's input.

---

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f9b731bdeccffa1b13e5edf4bc0428b8d49704e), the implementation in "[`git clean`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/066124da88a6d43d125b30a1bc8a66c2d8ef6423/Documentation/git-clean.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean))</sup> that makes `-n` and `-i` ignore `clean.requireForce` has been simplified, together with the documentation.

See [commit 105ec9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/105ec9ae8d0d100994ddf1ee5e99e4616558ff90) (03 Mar 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 12a4883](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12a4883feb53d08a80b3c049415105b0543f27a5) (03 Mar 2024) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 066124d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/066124da88a6d43d125b30a1bc8a66c2d8ef6423), 14 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`clean`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/105ec9ae8d0d100994ddf1ee5e99e4616558ff90): further clean-up of implementation around "--force"

> We clarified how "`clean.requireForce`" interacts with the "`--dry-run`" option in the previous commit, both in the implementation and in the documentation.
> Even when "[`git clean`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/105ec9ae8d0d100994ddf1ee5e99e4616558ff90/Documentation/git-clean.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean))</sup> (without other options) is required to be used with "`--force`" (i.e.
> either `clean.requireForce` is unset, or explicitly set to `true`) to protect end-users from casual invocation of the command by mistake, "`--dry-run`" does not require "`--force`" to be used, because it is already its own protection mechanism by being a no-op to the working tree files.
>
> The previous commit, however, missed another clean-up opportunity around the same area.
> Just like in the "`--dry-run`" mode, the command in the "`--interactive`" mode does not require "`--force`", either.
> This is because by going interactive and giving the end user one more chance to confirm, the mode itself is serving as its own protection mechanism.
>
> Let's take things one step further, and unify the code that defines interaction between "`--force`" and these two other options.
> Just like we added explanation for the reason why "`--dry-run`" does not honor "`clean.requireForce`", give an explanation for the reason why "`--interactive`" makes "`clean.requireForce`" to be ignored.

`git clean` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/105ec9ae8d0d100994ddf1ee5e99e4616558ff90/Documentation/git-clean.txt#L48-L49):

> Configuration variable `clean.requireForce` is ignored, as
> this mode gives its own safety protection by going interactive.